# How to stop UIWebView from caching CSS?

Tags: iphone, css, uiwebview, ipad, reload

I have an app which has in bundle a css file and more html files. When the user taps a button I change the css file and call [webView reload] but nothing happens. I think this is because the webview caches the old css file and reloads the page using that one.

How can I prevent this?

I tried using the info found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3549508/prevent-caching-of-css-files-in-uiwebview-loaded-from-disk) but I don't really understand what the technique is about.

Do I have to change the style.css somehow? Do I have to add the version variable to it?

because If I only use this line of code:

```
[htmlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"style.css" withString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"style.css?time=%@", [[NSDate date] description]]
```

my app crashes.

Any pointers of how to solve this problem would be great. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the same filename for both CSS files?  If you think that the UIWebView is caching one of them, then just name the other something different.