# display local html file with css in iphone..?

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

I want to display local html file that has css too in UIWebView. I am able to do that using following code..

```
NSURL *baseUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]];

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"info" ofType:@"html"];

NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path];
[webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:baseUrl];
```

I am not able to get hover effects and my understanding is my be there is no hover kind of thing in a touch mobile,

Any ways my main issue is I had deleted my index.html from resources and then re added the updated one but not getting the updated one..

I don't know what happen the web view still loads the old html file. I tried to clean project too.

Second thing can I get css effects in iphone..?

Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe if you reset your simulator (While running your simulator, go to iOS Simulator > Reset Content and Settings in the menu bar) then re-run your app, the UIWebView will load the new index.html. UIWebViews cache these things, so you can add code to clear that cache and/or ignore the cache. Check here: [Clearing UIWebview cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468553/clearing-uiwebview-cache/5606703#5606703)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you can only achieve this result by using javascript-events like `ontouchstart` (or something).

Comment: hello @Tim.. can you plz navigate me to any tutorial you are talking about.. Please.

Comment: I actually replied to your first question (hover-css), example (might contain some typos): `ontouchstart='this.className="over";'` and css: `#obj.over {color: red;}`.