# how to clear webview cache in ipad

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uiwebview

Here i have load the content in the uiwebview using

```
[webView loadHTMLString:[theApp.contentArr objectAtIndex:spineIndex] baseURL:url];
```

after going back and come i need to clear the cache

here i have tried these kinds of methods to clear the cache:

```
 [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.innerHTML = \"\";"];
    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"about:blank"]]];
    // remove all cached responses
        [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];

        // set an empty cache
    NSURLCache *sharedCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:0 diskCapacity:0 diskPath:nil];
    [NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:sharedCache];
```

but no use, what is the solution for this.....

Comment: Possible dupe of - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468553/clearing-uiwebview-cache

Comment: @rishi that question is based on url loading and i am to loading from html

Answer (score 2):

Easy way :

```
NSURLCache *sharedCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:0 diskCapacity:0 diskPath:nil];
[NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:sharedCache];
```

Answer (score 2):

Use -

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.innerHTML = \"\";"];

NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"about:blank"]];
[urlRequest setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];

[webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
```

Comment: it get crashed i the following line                         [urlRequest setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
 saying "NsUrlreqest may not respond to setcachepolicy"

Comment: sorry use NSMutableURLRequest instead of NSURLRequest.

Comment: thanx for ur help, its working but only for the first time alone. When loading again and again the cache is not removed...how to clear this...