# Black screen appears when viewing HTML5 the second time on UIWebView using iOS6

Tags: html, uiwebview, ios6

I'm displaying two HTML5 documents on my iPad application, using a UIWebView on iOS 6.0.1.
One of them has no problems and I can open and close the webview as much as I want. 
The other one can be displayed once and then when I close my web view and want to re-open the document again, the webview shows a black screen.

I haven't prepared the HTML5 documents myself and I don't have much knowledge on HTML5, so I can't tell the difference between them that causes this behavior.

Here's how I create my webview and how I load the HTML5:

```
UIWebView *theWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];

theWebView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
theWebView.clearsContextBeforeDrawing = YES;
theWebView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);

//adjust frame and add to view controller's view here

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.handypdf.net/davsan"];
[theWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:60.0]];
```

Everytime I open an HTML5 document, I re-create the web view. So I don't re-use it.

To fix the problem, I tried cleaning the cache, cookies, etc.. explained on [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10686748/how-to-clear-webview-cache-in-ipad) SO answers, but it didn't work.

Here are the links to the problematic and the not-problematic HTML documents:

[This one](https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/gskprodg/PRO13D22D.zip) works ok.
[This one](https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/gskprodg/PRO14598D.zip) doesn't work the second time.

Also, if you want to check these HTML5 pages online here are the links to them:

[This one](http://www.handypdf.net/davsan2/AU_MIDAS_HTML5/) works ok. 
[This one](http://www.handypdf.net/davsan/) doesn't work the second time.

This problem does not happen on iOS 5.x. It's also replicable using the iOS simulator.
What would you suggest to fix it?

Thx

Comment: I'm having this exact problem now it seems.  Did you happen to make any progress with this?

Comment: Me too, please let us know...

Comment: Hey guys, I put how I dealt with this on the answer. Hope this works for you too...

Answer (score 0):

Not a satisfying answer, but here's how I progressed with this problem:

I couldn't solve this for a couple of days. Then I deleted all my code and re-wrote the functionality from scratch, and then it was solved. I couldn't understand the exact reason, because I didn't write anything fancy on my second attempt, so unfortunately I can't tell how it's solved :(

Here is what I just did:

Create the web view once, and cache it:

```
+(UIWebView *)getTheWebView {
    if (theWebView) return theWebView;

    theWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
    theWebView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
    theWebView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);
    return theWebView;
}
```

Then, when I want to show the web view:

```
UIWebView *theWebView = [HTML5Manager getTheWebView];
theWebView.frame = self.view.frame;

[self.view addSubview:theWebView];
```

And here's how I load the URL:

```
[theWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:60.0]];
```

This is just it and it works. I know it doesn't make sense but I hope it helps you, too...