# How do you clear the WebView cache in Cocoa?

Tags: macos, cocoa, webview

How do you clear/flush the [WebView](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Classes/WebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) cache in a Cocoa app?

In particular, I would like to clear the cache of a local stylesheet.

I have tried the following to no avail:

```
// Tried this before loadRequest
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];

// Also tried this before and after loadRequest
[webView.mainFrame reloadFromOrigin];
```

Even replacing the `WebView` with a new one still uses the cached stylesheet.

Comment: Look at this discussion http://stackoverflow.com/a/5606703/1578508

Comment: @lukaswelte Nothing in there worked.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The other suggested solutions didn't work for the local stylesheet (though they should work for remote resources).

I finally managed to solve this via the [resourceLoadDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Protocols/WebResourceLoadDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003836), by explicitly setting the cache policy:

```
- (NSURLRequest *)webView:(WebView *)sender resource:(id)identifier willSendRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request redirectResponse:(NSURLResponse *)redirectResponse fromDataSource:(WebDataSource *)dataSource {
    request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[request URL] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:[request timeoutInterval]];
    return request;
}
```

Fun stuff.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be working for me. OSX 10.10.3.

Comment: This didn't work for me either on 10.12.  Only solution I found so far was to embed the local stylesheet, rather than linking to it.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [NSURLCache Class Reference.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLCache_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

```
- (id)initWithMemoryCapacity:(NSUInteger)memoryCapacity diskCapacity:(NSUInteger)diskCapacity diskPath:(NSString *)path 
//set memoryCapacity and diskCapacity to 0 bytes and diskPath to nil

NSURLCache *Cache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:0 diskCapacity:0 diskPath:nil];
[NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:Cache];
```

Comment: Interesting but doesn't appear to work. A cache of the local stylesheet is still loaded.