# NSURLProtocol - startLoading not invoked

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlprotocol

Since upgrading to iOS 9.1 my custom `NSURLProtocol`, won't invoke `-(void)startLoading` anymore. Has anyone else experienced this ?

Everything worked fine on iOS 8 ...

Code:

```
@implementation RZCustomProtocol
@dynamic request;

+ (BOOL)canInitWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
{
    if ([request.URL.scheme isEqualToString:@"imsweb"]) {
        NSLog(@"%@", @"YES");
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}

+ (NSURLRequest *)canonicalRequestForRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request {
    return request;
}

+ (BOOL)requestIsCacheEquivalent:(NSURLRequest *)a toRequest:(NSURLRequest *)b {
    return [super requestIsCacheEquivalent:a toRequest:b];
}

- (void)startLoading {
    NSLog(@"STARTLOADING: %@", [self.request.URL absoluteString]);
    NSString *filename = [[self.request.URL lastPathComponent] stringByDeletingPathExtension];
    NSLog(@"%@", filename);
    NSString *videoUrl = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:filename ofType:@"mp4"];
    NSData *video = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:videoUrl];
    NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)video.length);
    NSHTTPURLResponse *response = [[NSHTTPURLResponse alloc] initWithURL:self.request.URL
                                                              statusCode:200 HTTPVersion:nil headerFields:@{
                                                                                                            @"Content-Length": [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)video.length],
                                                                                                            @"Content-Type": @"video/mp4",
                                                                                                            }];

    [self.client URLProtocol:self didReceiveResponse:response cacheStoragePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageNotAllowed];
    [self.client URLProtocol:self didLoadData:video];
    [self.client URLProtocolDidFinishLoading:self];
}

- (void)stopLoading {
    NSLog(@"STOPLOADING: %@", [self.request.URL absoluteString]);
}
```

Comment: Check [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26390036/nsurlprotocol-isnt-asked-to-load-after-yes-response-to-caninitwithrequest) out. This may help you!

Comment: @Abhinav thank you, but startLoading() ist not even called once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. In my case, I was adding an iframe to the page dynamically using JavaScript and loading my custom protocol content in that. In iOS 9.1 the `WebView` refuses to load the iframe content when the main document is accessed over https, but it works fine over http. This looks like a new security control, to avoid loading insecure resources over a secure session.

The fix I went with was to change my scheme to use `https`. For example, use `https://imsweb/...` instead of `imsweb://`. It's a bit of a hack but the best solution I could find.

Something like:

```
+ (BOOL)canInitWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
{
    if ([request.URL.scheme isEqualToString:@"https"] &&
            [request.URL.host isEqualToString:@"imsweb"]) {
        NSLog(@"%@", @"YES");
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

and of course you need to reconstruct the correct URL in `startLoading`.

Comment: This could be a possible solution, but unfortunately i will not be able to test this anymore. For the use case: We had a booth at a fair, where the internet connection was too slow for streaming it from our media server. So my solution was to host this media server on my laptop together with a proxy. Then i connected the iPads to the proxy and forwarded the media requests to this local instance, while passing the rest to the internet. Since this works for you, I mark it as solution.