# UIWebView crashed in iOS 10

Tags: swift, uiwebview, ios10, linkedin-api, uiwebviewdelegate

I am implementing the LinkedIn sign in using `UIWebView`

Here is my code

```
import UIKit

typealias LinkedInLoginCallBack = ([String:String]?,String,Error?) -> Void

class LinkedInWebViewController: UIViewController,UIWebViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var linkedinWebView: UIWebView!
    @IBOutlet weak var indicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!
    var userDidLogin:LinkedInLoginCallBack!

    let linkedInKey = "xxxx"

    let linkedInSecret = "xxxx"

    let authorizationEndPoint = "https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization"

    let accessTokenEndPoint = "https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        linkedinWebView.delegate = self
        self.startAuthorization()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func startAuthorization() {
        let responseType = "code"
        let redirectURL = "https://example.com/login/check-linkedin".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlFragmentAllowed)!

        let state = "xxxxx" 

        let scope = "r_basicprofile,r_emailaddress"

        var authorizationURL = "\(authorizationEndPoint)?"
        authorizationURL += "response_type=\(responseType)&"
        authorizationURL += "client_id=\(linkedInKey)&"
        authorizationURL += "redirect_uri=\(redirectURL)&"
        authorizationURL += "state=\(state)&"
        authorizationURL += "scope=\(scope)"

        // logout already logined user or revoke tokens
        logout()

        // Create a URL request and load it in the web view.
        let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: authorizationURL)!)
        linkedinWebView.loadRequest(request)
    }

    func logout(){
        let revokeUrl = "https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/invalidateToken"
        let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: revokeUrl)!)
        linkedinWebView.loadRequest(request)
    }

    func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebView.NavigationType) -> Bool {
        let url = request.url!
        if url.host == "https://example.com/login/check-linkedin" {
            if url.absoluteString.range(of: "code") != nil {
                let urlParts = url.absoluteString.components(separatedBy: "?")   
                let code = urlParts[1].components(separatedBy: "=")[1]

                requestForAccessToken(authorizationCode: code)
             }

        }
        return true
    }

    func webViewDidStartLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
        indicator.startAnimating()
    }

    func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
        indicator.stopAnimating()
    }

    func requestForAccessToken(authorizationCode: String) {
        let grantType = "authorization_code"

        let redirectURL = "https://example.com/login/check-linkedin".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)!


        // Set the POST parameters.
        var postParams = "grant_type=\(grantType)&"
        postParams += "code=\(authorizationCode)&"
        postParams += "redirect_uri=\(redirectURL)&"
        postParams += "client_id=\(linkedInKey)&"
        postParams += "client_secret=\(linkedInSecret)"


        // Convert the POST parameters into a NSData object.
        let postData = postParams.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

        // Initialize a mutable URL request object using the access token endpoint URL string.
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: accessTokenEndPoint)! as URL)

        // Indicate that we're about to make a POST request.
        request.httpMethod = "POST"

        // Set the HTTP body using the postData object created above.
        request.httpBody = postData
        // Add the required HTTP header field.
        request.addValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded;", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        // Initialize a NSURLSession object.
        let session = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)

        // Make the request.
        let task: URLSessionDataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            // Get the HTTP status code of the request.
            let statusCode = (response as! HTTPURLResponse).statusCode

            if statusCode == 200 {
                // Convert the received JSON data into a dictionary.
                do {
                    let dataDictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! NSDictionary
                    print("dataDictionary\(dataDictionary)")
                    let accessToken = dataDictionary["access_token"] as! String

                    var socialAuth:[String:String] = [String:String]()
                    socialAuth[SignupAPIController.KEY_PARAM_SOCIAL_TYPE] = SocialMediaType.instagram.rawValue
                    socialAuth[SignupAPIController.KEY_PARAM_SOCIAL_ID] = dataDictionary["username"] as? String
                    socialAuth[SignupAPIController.KEY_PARAM_SOCIAL_TOKEN] = accessToken
                    socialAuth[SignupAPIController.KEY_PARAM_SOCIAL_RTOKEN] = accessToken
                    socialAuth["name"] = dataDictionary["full_name"] as? String
                    socialAuth["email"] = dataDictionary["username"] as? String

                    self.userDidLogin(socialAuth,accessToken,nil)


                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }
                } catch {
                    print("Could not convert JSON data into a dictionary.")
                }
            }else{
                print("cancel clicked")
            }
        }

        task.resume()
    }
}
```

But don't know it crashes my app after some time because of the below error

```
 thread #20, name = 'WebThread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x2ffffff6b)
```

Here it is my stack trace

```
(lldb) bt
* thread #16, name = 'WebThread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x2ffffff6b)
  * frame #0: 0x000000018fda66e4 JavaScriptCore`llint_entry + 15716
    frame #1: 0x000000018fc75a88 JavaScriptCore`JSC::JITCode::execute(JSC::VM*, JSC::ProtoCallFrame*) + 168
    frame #2: 0x000000018f6c75fc JavaScriptCore`JSC::Interpreter::executeCall(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::JSObject*, JSC::CallType, JSC::CallData const&, JSC::JSValue, JSC::ArgList const&) + 352
    frame #3: 0x000000018fca616c JavaScriptCore`JSC::boundThisNoArgsFunctionCall(JSC::ExecState*) + 448
    frame #4: 0x000000018fda9450 JavaScriptCore`llint_entry + 27344
    frame #5: 0x000000018fda89d4 JavaScriptCore`llint_entry + 24660
    frame #6: 0x000000018fda8a38 JavaScriptCore`llint_entry + 24760
    frame #7: 0x000000018fda27b8 JavaScriptCore`vmEntryToJavaScript + 264
    frame #8: 0x000000018fc75a88 JavaScriptCore`JSC::JITCode::execute(JSC::VM*, JSC::ProtoCallFrame*) + 168
    frame #9: 0x000000018f6c75fc JavaScriptCore`JSC::Interpreter::executeCall(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::JSObject*, JSC::CallType, JSC::CallData const&, JSC::JSValue, JSC::ArgList const&) + 352
    frame #10: 0x000000018fca616c JavaScriptCore`JSC::boundThisNoArgsFunctionCall(JSC::ExecState*) + 448
    frame #11: 0x000000018fda9450 JavaScriptCore`llint_entry + 27344
    frame #12: 0x000000018fda89d4 JavaScriptCore`llint_entry + 24660
    frame #13: 0x000000018fda89d4 JavaScriptCore`llint_entry + 24660
    frame #14: 0x000000018fda27b8 JavaScriptCore`vmEntryToJavaScript + 264
    frame #15: 0x000000018fc75a88 JavaScriptCore`JSC::JITCode::execute(JSC::VM*, JSC::ProtoCallFrame*) + 168
    frame #16: 0x000000018f6c75fc JavaScriptCore`JSC::Interpreter::executeCall(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::JSObject*, JSC::CallType, JSC::CallData const&, JSC::JSValue, JSC::ArgList const&) + 352
    frame #17: 0x000000018fca616c JavaScriptCore`JSC::boundThisNoArgsFunctionCall(JSC::ExecState*) + 448
    frame #18: 0x000000018fda9450 JavaScriptCore`llint_entry + 27344
    frame #19: 0x000000018fda89d4 JavaScriptCore`llint_entry + 24660
    frame #20: 0x000000018fda8a38 JavaScriptCore`llint_entry + 24760
    frame #21: 0x000000018fda27b8 JavaScriptCore`vmEntryToJavaScript + 264
    frame #22: 0x000000018fc75a88 JavaScriptCore`JSC::JITCode::execute(JSC::VM*, JSC::ProtoCallFrame*) + 168
    frame #23: 0x000000018f6c75fc JavaScriptCore`JSC::Interpreter::executeCall(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::JSObject*, JSC::CallType, JSC::CallData const&, JSC::JSValue, JSC::ArgList const&) + 352
    frame #24: 0x000000018fca616c JavaScriptCore`JSC::boundThisNoArgsFunctionCall(JSC::ExecState*) + 448
    frame #25: 0x000000018fda9450 JavaScriptCore`llint_entry + 27344
    frame #26: 0x000000018fda89d4 JavaScriptCore`llint_entry + 24660
    frame #27: 0x000000018fda27b8 JavaScriptCore`vmEntryToJavaScript + 264
    frame #28: 0x000000018fc75a88 JavaScriptCore`JSC::JITCode::execute(JSC::VM*, JSC::ProtoCallFrame*) + 168
    frame #29: 0x000000018f6c75fc JavaScriptCore`JSC::Interpreter::executeCall(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::JSObject*, JSC::CallType, JSC::CallData const&, JSC::JSValue, JSC::ArgList const&) + 352
    frame #30: 0x000000018fca616c JavaScriptCore`JSC::boundThisNoArgsFunctionCall(JSC::ExecState*) + 448
    frame #31: 0x000000018fda9450 JavaScriptCore`llint_entry + 27344
    frame #32: 0x000000018fda89d4 JavaScriptCore`llint_entry + 24660
    frame #33: 0x000000018fda8a38 JavaScriptCore`llint_entry + 24760
    frame #34: 0x000000018fda27b8 JavaScriptCore`vmEntryToJavaScript + 264
    frame #35: 0x000000018fc75a88 JavaScriptCore`JSC::JITCode::execute(JSC::VM*, JSC::ProtoCallFrame*) + 168
    frame #36: 0x000000018f6c75fc JavaScriptCore`JSC::Interpreter::executeCall(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::JSObject*, JSC::CallType, JSC::CallData const&, JSC::JSValue, JSC::ArgList const&) + 352
    frame #37: 0x000000018fca616c JavaScriptCore`JSC::boundThisNoArgsFunctionCall(JSC::ExecState*) + 448
    frame #38: 0x000000018fda9450 JavaScriptCore`llint_entry + 27344
    frame #39: 0x000000018fda89d4 JavaScriptCore`llint_entry + 24660
    frame #40: 0x000000018fda8a38 JavaScriptCore`llint_entry + 24760
    frame #41: 0x000000018fda8a38 JavaScriptCore`llint_entry + 24760
    frame #42: 0x000000018fda27b8 JavaScriptCore`vmEntryToJavaScript + 264
    frame #43: 0x000000018fc75a88 JavaScriptCore`JSC::JITCode::execute(JSC::VM*, JSC::ProtoCallFrame*) + 168
    frame #44: 0x000000018f6c75fc JavaScriptCore`JSC::Interpreter::executeCall(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::JSObject*, JSC::CallType, JSC::CallData const&, JSC::JSValue, JSC::ArgList const&) + 352
    frame #45: 0x000000018fca616c JavaScriptCore`JSC::boundThisNoArgsFunctionCall(JSC::ExecState*) + 448
    frame #46: 0x000000018fda9450 JavaScriptCore`llint_entry + 27344
    frame #47: 0x000000018fda89d4 JavaScriptCore`llint_entry + 24660
    frame #48: 0x000000018fda8a38 JavaScriptCore`llint_entry + 24760
    frame #49: 0x000000018fda8a38 JavaScriptCore`llint_entry + 24760
    frame #50: 0x000000018fda27b8 JavaScriptCore`vmEntryToJavaScript + 264
    frame #51: 0x000000018fc75a88 JavaScriptCore`JSC::JITCode::execute(JSC::VM*, JSC::ProtoCallFrame*) + 168
    frame #52: 0x000000018f6c75fc JavaScriptCore`JSC::Interpreter::executeCall(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::JSObject*, JSC::CallType, JSC::CallData const&, JSC::JSValue, JSC::ArgList const&) + 352
    frame #53: 0x000000018fca616c JavaScriptCore`JSC::boundThisNoArgsFunctionCall(JSC::ExecState*) + 448
    frame #54: 0x000000018fda9450 JavaScriptCore`llint_entry + 27344
    frame #55: 0x000000018fda89d4 JavaScriptCore`llint_entry + 24660
    frame #56: 0x000000018fda27b8 JavaScriptCore`vmEntryToJavaScript + 264
    frame #57: 0x000000018fc75a88 JavaScriptCore`JSC::JITCode::execute(JSC::VM*, JSC::ProtoCallFrame*) + 168
    frame #58: 0x000000018f6c75fc JavaScriptCore`JSC::Interpreter::executeCall(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::JSObject*, JSC::CallType, JSC::CallData const&, JSC::JSValue, JSC::ArgList const&) + 352
    frame #59: 0x000000018fca616c JavaScriptCore`JSC::boundThisNoArgsFunctionCall(JSC::ExecState*) + 448
    frame #60: 0x000000018fda9450 JavaScriptCore`llint_entry + 27344
    frame #61: 0x000000018fda89d4 JavaScriptCore`llint_entry + 24660
    frame #62: 0x000000018fda8a38 JavaScriptCore`llint_entry + 24760
    frame #63: 0x000000018fda27b8 JavaScriptCore`vmEntryToJavaScript + 264
    frame #64: 0x000000018fc75a88 JavaScriptCore`JSC::JITCode::execute(JSC::VM*, JSC::ProtoCallFrame*) + 168
    frame #65: 0x000000018f6c75fc JavaScriptCore`JSC::Interpreter::executeCall(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::JSObject*, JSC::CallType, JSC::CallData const&, JSC::JSValue, JSC::ArgList const&) + 352
    frame #66: 0x000000018fca616c JavaScriptCore`JSC::boundThisNoArgsFunctionCall(JSC::ExecState*) + 448
    frame #67: 0x000000018fda9450 JavaScriptCore`llint_entry + 27344
    frame #68: 0x000000018fda89d4 JavaScriptCore`llint_entry + 24660
    frame #69: 0x000000018fda89d4 JavaScriptCore`llint_entry + 24660
    frame #70: 0x000000018fda27b8 JavaScriptCore`vmEntryToJavaScript + 264
    frame #71: 0x000000018fc75a88 JavaScriptCore`JSC::JITCode::execute(JSC::VM*, JSC::ProtoCallFrame*) + 168
    frame #72: 0x000000018f6c75fc JavaScriptCore`JSC::Interpreter::executeCall(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::JSObject*, JSC::CallType, JSC::CallData const&, JSC::JSValue, JSC::ArgList const&) + 352
    frame #73: 0x000000018fca616c JavaScriptCore`JSC::boundThisNoArgsFunctionCall(JSC::ExecState*) + 448
    frame #74: 0x000000018fda9450 JavaScriptCore`llint_entry + 27344
    frame #75: 0x000000018fda89d4 JavaScriptCore`llint_entry + 24660
    frame #76: 0x000000018fda8a38 JavaScriptCore`llint_entry + 24760
    frame #77: 0x000000018fda8a38 JavaScriptCore`llint_entry + 24760
    frame #78: 0x000000018fda8a38 JavaScriptCore`llint_entry + 24760
    frame #79: 0x000000018fda8a38 JavaScriptCore`llint_entry + 24760
    frame #80: 0x000000018fda8a38 JavaScriptCore`llint_entry + 24760
    frame #81: 0x000000018fda27b8 JavaScriptCore`vmEntryToJavaScript + 264
    frame #82: 0x000000018fc75a88 JavaScriptCore`JSC::JITCode::execute(JSC::VM*, JSC::ProtoCallFrame*) + 168
    frame #83: 0x000000018f6c75fc JavaScriptCore`JSC::Interpreter::executeCall(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::JSObject*, JSC::CallType, JSC::CallData const&, JSC::JSValue, JSC::ArgList const&) + 352
    frame #84: 0x000000018fca616c JavaScriptCore`JSC::boundThisNoArgsFunctionCall(JSC::ExecState*) + 448
    frame #85: 0x000000018fda9450 JavaScriptCore`llint_entry + 27344
    frame #86: 0x000000018fda8a38 JavaScriptCore`llint_entry + 24760
    frame #87: 0x000000018fda27b8 JavaScriptCore`vmEntryToJavaScript + 264
    frame #88: 0x000000018fc75a88 JavaScriptCore`JSC::JITCode::execute(JSC::VM*, JSC::ProtoCallFrame*) + 168
    frame #89: 0x000000018f6c75fc JavaScriptCore`JSC::Interpreter::executeCall(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::JSObject*, JSC::CallType, JSC::CallData const&, JSC::JSValue, JSC::ArgList const&) + 352
    frame #90: 0x000000018fca616c JavaScriptCore`JSC::boundThisNoArgsFunctionCall(JSC::ExecState*) + 448
    frame #91: 0x000000018fda9450 JavaScriptCore`llint_entry + 27344
    frame #92: 0x000000018fda89d4 JavaScriptCore`llint_entry + 24660
    frame #93: 0x000000018fda8a38 JavaScriptCore`llint_entry + 24760
    frame #94: 0x000000018fda27b8 JavaScriptCore`vmEntryToJavaScript + 264
    frame #95: 0x000000018fc75a88 JavaScriptCore`JSC::JITCode::execute(JSC::VM*, JSC::ProtoCallFrame*) + 168
    frame #96: 0x000000018f6c75fc JavaScriptCore`JSC::Interpreter::executeCall(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::JSObject*, JSC::CallType, JSC::CallData const&, JSC::JSValue, JSC::ArgList const&) + 352
    frame #97: 0x000000018fca616c JavaScriptCore`JSC::boundThisNoArgsFunctionCall(JSC::ExecState*) + 448
    frame #98: 0x000000018fda9450 JavaScriptCore`llint_entry + 27344
    frame #99: 0x000000018fda8a38 JavaScriptCore`llint_entry + 24760
    frame #100: 0x000000018fda27b8 JavaScriptCore`vmEntryToJavaScript + 264
    frame #101: 0x000000018fc75a88 JavaScriptCore`JSC::JITCode::execute(JSC::VM*, JSC::ProtoCallFrame*) + 168
    frame #102: 0x000000018f6c75fc JavaScriptCore`JSC::Interpreter::executeCall(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::JSObject*, JSC::CallType, JSC::CallData const&, JSC::JSValue, JSC::ArgList const&) + 352
    frame #103: 0x000000018f93a2a8 JavaScriptCore`JSC::profiledCall(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::ProfilingReason, JSC::JSValue, JSC::CallType, JSC::CallData const&, JSC::JSValue, JSC::ArgList const&, WTF::NakedPtr<JSC::Exception>&) + 164
    frame #104: 0x0000000190340a10 WebCore`WebCore::JSEventListener::handleEvent(WebCore::ScriptExecutionContext*, WebCore::Event*) + 992
    frame #105: 0x00000001906748d8 WebCore`WebCore::EventTarget::fireEventListeners(WebCore::Event&, WebCore::EventTargetData*, WTF::Vector<WebCore::RegisteredEventListener, 1ul, WTF::CrashOnOverflow, 16ul>&) + 620
    frame #106: 0x0000000190674588 WebCore`WebCore::EventTarget::fireEventListeners(WebCore::Event&) + 328
    frame #107: 0x000000019067442c WebCore`WebCore::EventTarget::dispatchEvent(WebCore::Event&) + 108
    frame #108: 0x00000001906743ac WebCore`WebCore::EventTarget::dispatchEventForBindings(WebCore::Event*, int&) + 116
    frame #109: 0x00000001909eb22c WebCore`WebCore::jsEventTargetPrototypeFunctionDispatchEvent(JSC::ExecState*) + 260
    frame #110: 0x000000018fda9450 JavaScriptCore`llint_entry + 27344
    frame #111: 0x000000018fda8a38 JavaScriptCore`llint_entry + 24760
    frame #112: 0x000000018fda8a38 JavaScriptCore`llint_entry + 24760
    frame #113: 0x000000018fda27b8 JavaScriptCore`vmEntryToJavaScript + 264
    frame #114: 0x000000018fc75a88 JavaScriptCore`JSC::JITCode::execute(JSC::VM*, JSC::ProtoCallFrame*) + 168
    frame #115: 0x000000018f6b0480 JavaScriptCore`JSC::Interpreter::execute(JSC::ProgramExecutable*, JSC::ExecState*, JSC::JSObject*) + 13724
    frame #116: 0x000000018f9936f4 JavaScriptCore`JSC::evaluate(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::SourceCode const&, JSC::JSValue, WTF::NakedPtr<JSC::Exception>&) + 440
    frame #117: 0x0000000190ec88a0 WebCore`WebCore::ScriptController::evaluateInWorld(WebCore::ScriptSourceCode const&, WebCore::DOMWrapperWorld&, WebCore::ExceptionDetails*) + 328
    frame #118: 0x0000000190224c84 WebCore`WebCore::ScriptElement::executeScript(WebCore::ScriptSourceCode const&) + 612
    frame #119: 0x00000001902a0448 WebCore`WebCore::HTMLScriptRunner::executePendingScriptAndDispatchEvent(WebCore::PendingScript&) + 212
    frame #120: 0x000000019026b5a8 WebCore`WebCore::HTMLScriptRunner::executeScriptsWaitingForParsing() + 88
    frame #121: 0x000000019078b53c WebCore`non-virtual thunk to WebCore::HTMLDocumentParser::notifyFinished(WebCore::CachedResource*) + 52
    frame #122: 0x000000019029d8b8 WebCore`WebCore::CachedResource::checkNotify() + 448
    frame #123: 0x000000019029d59c WebCore`WebCore::SubresourceLoader::didFinishLoading(double) + 1020
    frame #124: 0x000000018c00e788 CFNetwork`__65-[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:]_block_invoke + 80
    frame #125: 0x000000018c00e718 CFNetwork`-[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:] + 200
    frame #126: 0x000000018c00e88c CFNetwork`-[NSURLConnectionInternal _withActiveConnectionAndDelegate:] + 56
    frame #127: 0x000000018bf393dc CFNetwork`___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic23_delegate_cacheTrifectaEPK20_CFCachedURLResponseU13block_pointerFvvE_block_invoke + 576
    frame #128: 0x000000018bf34960 CFNetwork`___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic18_withDelegateAsyncEPKcU13block_pointerFvP16_CFURLConnectionPK33CFURLConnectionClientCurrent_VMaxE_block_invoke_2 + 108
    frame #129: 0x00000001033e921c libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 16
    frame #130: 0x00000001033f3c9c libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 400
    frame #131: 0x000000018bfebeb4 CFNetwork`RunloopBlockContext::_invoke_block(void const*, void*) + 36
    frame #132: 0x000000018b6a79a8 CoreFoundation`CFArrayApplyFunction + 68
    frame #133: 0x000000018bfebd98 CFNetwork`RunloopBlockContext::perform() + 136
    frame #134: 0x000000018bfed0c0 CFNetwork`MultiplexerSource::perform() + 312
    frame #135: 0x000000018bfece2c CFNetwork`MultiplexerSource::_perform(void*) + 64
    frame #136: 0x000000018b77c278 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
    frame #137: 0x000000018b77bbc0 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 524
    frame #138: 0x000000018b7797c0 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 804
    frame #139: 0x000000018b6a8048 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
    frame #140: 0x000000019025845c WebCore`RunWebThread(void*) + 456
    frame #141: 0x000000018a864850 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_body + 240
    frame #142: 0x000000018a864760 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_start + 284
    frame #143: 0x000000018a861dac libsystem_pthread.dylib`thread_start + 4
```

Comment: Where exactly is it crashing?

Comment: it is thread crashing...not in specific line

Comment: Put a `Swift Error` breakpoint in Xcode and find out which line crashes exactly.

Comment: Yes tried it doesn't redirect to me specific line

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: yes sure I am putting stack trace

Comment: It looks like this is related. Here's a couple things you could do to see where this is coming from https://stackoverflow.com/a/40731008/6448167