# Using Web View I am Loading The Interactive Meeting Monitor Room Url Continuously (Whole Day).After 4 to 5 hours It Is Unresponsive

Tags: ios, iphone, uiwebview, ios9

My `webView` is **Interactive Meeting Room** and it has `UIButton` to book the room. But as I mentioned in the title After Continuous Running Say 5 hours I was unable to book the room because web view is Unresponsive.
My code is...

```
NSString *urlstr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"My url"];
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:urlstr];
NSURLRequest *request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[self.myWebView loadRequest:request];
[self.myWebView setDelegate:self];
```

It is in iOS9,xCode 7.

Comment: maybe try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468553/clearing-uiwebview-cache) after some time?

Comment: I have Used This code it's Not Working.... Thanks.

Comment: Please any body Answer it ...