# How to remove access token from uber API while logout?

Tags: ios, swift, uber-api

I am doing integrate uber sdk using oAuth2Client in ios.I got access token using 
" https://login.uber.com/oauth/v2/token" but when I was trying to remove token using "https://login.uber.com/oauth/revoke" I got response code "200" but access token not be nill so I am not able to redirect on login screen.[image]and
I directly redirect into [image]

If anyone do uber integration in ios application.Please help me!!

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `POST /oauth/revoke` invalidates the `access_token`, `refresh_token` pair that you have for that user.

However, that user is probably still logged into Uber.com and has an active & valid session with a cookie in the browser.

You probably do not want to log the user out of the browser session, but if you did want to you could direct them to `https://riders.uber.com/logout`

Comment: :As you suggest I had direct to https://riders.uber.com/logout but when I again logged in it is not direct to my app using "callback" url.and it directly redirect in "https://riders.uber.com/trips".Can you please tell me how can i redirect in my app.

Comment: If i want to remove cooies and session for uber how can i do it?

Comment: @Donal You have to tell the WebView to clear it's cache or cookie jar/storage. For UIWebView see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468553/clearing-uiwebview-cache Your question is iOS WebView implementation specific and doesn't have much to do with the Uber API.

Comment: @Mnemonic:Thanks but I have already removed cookies from browser.but thing is when I remove cookies and redirect uisng " [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://login.uber.com/login"]]" and logged in it's direct to uber app not in my using call back url "lookatme://oauth/callback"