# Uber logout/login with different user results in showing previous logged in user on iOS

Tags: ios, cookies, uber-api

I am currently using a SFSafariViewController to log users in the uber api. SFSafariViewController does not give you access to delete the uber cookies manually after logging out.

I have read this issue : [How to remove access token from uber API while logout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36623918/how-to-remove-access-token-from-uber-api-while-logout)

My problem is the I can login and logout with a first user. I can login with a second user but it shows me the name of the previous user.

I revoke the tokens properly and than call the link https://riders.uber.com/logout.

I was wondering if there was a way for the call https://riders.uber.com/logout to clear the cookies set from the previous login attempt. If the page itself could clear the cookie while loading or if there was a query parameter I could give it to clear it.

This would allow me to use SFSafariViewController directly without doing custom WebView/Cookie management implementation.

Could it just be a bug in the logout uber page not clearing the auth/sessions cookies properly ?

Comment: Did you check following SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468553/clearing-uiwebview-cache. It may help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, technically we should not have to manually clear the cookies since we are calling https://riders.uber.com/logout.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect to https://login.uber.com/logout to force the logout across all uber properties.

Comment: Hi, it seems that with this url nothing gets cleared and when I sign back in SFSafariViewController, it sign me up automatically. Which is not what I want.