# Xcode: WebView refreshes/reloads after endRefreshing()

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, delay, pull-to-refresh

I have an iOS app build with Xcode and Swift.

When I pull to refresh the activityIndicator spins.
When I release the animation/spin will stop immediately but the website only refreshes/reloads after ca. 3/4-1 seconds.

Is there a way to show the animation/spin wheel till the end of refreshing?
This is my code:

```
    func pullToRefresh() {
        self.homewebview.reload()
        self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
//        NSURLCache.sharedURLCache().removeAllCachedResponses()
    }
    func addRefreshControl() {
        refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
        refreshControl.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Einen Moment bitte…")
        refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(FirstViewController.pullToRefresh), forControlEvents:.ValueChanged)
        self.homewebview.scrollView.addSubview(refreshControl)
        refreshControl.tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the `endRefreshing` method of `UIRefreshControl` in delegate method of `UIWebViewDelegate` like this

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.webView.delegate = self
}

func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
    self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
}
```

Also remove `self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()` from `pullToRefresh` method.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Hi, thanks for trying to help me. The animation and spinning wheel don't disappear now. The wheel spins all time.

Comment: You need to set the delegate of your `webView` object to `self`. Check my edited answer.

Comment: For `self.webView.delegate = self` I get: Cannot assign value of type 'MyViewController' to type 'UIWebViewDelegate?'

Comment: I have to do it like this, right? Code: `class MyViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {`

Comment: Yes also add this `webViewDidFinishLoad` delegate method of `UIWebViewDelegate` in your `MyViewController` like i did in answer.

Comment: @David Welcome, Happy Coding :)

Comment: Small question: When adding `NSURLCache.sharedURLCache().removeAllCachedResponses()` to `pullToRefresh` all cache will deleted when refreshing, right?

Comment: Read this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5606703/6433023) it will give you whole idea about `NSURLCache`.