# How to clear cache in iOS10?

Tags: ios, ios10, clear-cache

I am trying to clear cache in iOS 10. But `removeAllCachedResponses` is not working. Is `removeAllCachedResponses` broken in iOS10. As this working in iOS 9.

Comment: Are you seen this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5606703/3941304)?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're talking about?

```
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
```

You can also modify the cache behavior of your requests to selectively cache responses. If you're using `AFNetworking` by chance, you can use `setCacheResponseBlock`. E.g. in one project I set it to return `nil` for all large video and audio files. But allow it to cache smaller image files.

```
[streamingOperation setCacheResponseBlock:^NSCachedURLResponse *(NSURLConnection *connection, NSCachedURLResponse *cachedResponse) {
    return nil; // Ensures we are not unecessarily caching asset data to Cache.db
}];
```

Comment: my application requires to clear all cache response.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to delete file from application directory. 
There are many ways path of **File from Directory**, following is one of them.

```
NSArray *myPathList = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *mainPath    = [myPathList  objectAtIndex:0];

mainPath = [mainPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:DirectoryName];
```

Now you can delete file at this path the **mainPath** is Full Path of File.

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSError *error;
BOOL fileExists = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:mainPath];

if (fileExists)
{
     BOOL success = [fileManager removeItemAtPath:mainPath error:&error];
     if (!success) NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);

}
```