# How to clear cache of a WebView embedded in a iOS app

Tags: ios, caching, webview

I have a hybrid iOS application using a WebView to show the web content. How to clear the cache of the WebView? Not even reinstalling the app clears the cache.

My problem is there are assets cached by the WebView that I have to update.

Comment: See if this answers what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468553/clearing-uiwebview-cache

Comment: No, I need to clear the cache from outside the code for example a system call or maybe there is a app doing that.