# Uneven font size in rendering epub

Tags: ios, uiwebview, epub

I am using aepubreader code for rendering epub in my application. The issue I am facing is that the first book is loaded perfectly , but when I switch to other book from the menu ,the book is rendered with uneven font size and the format is distorted completely. But if the same book is opened during the fresh launch of application the book is rendered properly. The issue seems to be related to caching of css file in the Webview. Has anyone faced this kind of issue ? kindly suggest the way to ignore caching of css in the webview. I had set the cache policy to `NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData` Also I had set the cache size to zero as follows

```
 NSURLCache *sharedCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:0 diskCapacity:0 diskPath:nil];
    [NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:sharedCache];
    [sharedCache release];
```

But still didnt help out to solve the issue.

Comment: Solved it with the help of following post :: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3549508/prevent-caching-of-css-files-in-uiwebview-loaded-from-disk